# Voice chat through wifi in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

Please provide me guidance for wifi voice chat.

I have gone through all the related topics for voice chat iPhone sdk in Stack Overflow and many other sites.

GAMEKIT framework provides voice chat functionality for both Bluetooth and internet connection too.
By changing mask type to :

```
picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline
```

`GKPeerPickerController` provides UI for bluetooth connection only.

For using internet connection we need to create our own UI that shows different wifi connections.

So, how to create to create UI for wifi.( or is dhr any other solution for wifi voice chat)

Waiting for guidance.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to treat this is to work with GKSession by yourself. GKSession manages to find nearby users via wifi automatically. If you need something like really online, via the Internet, you will need your own server to "track" each user.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Eduardo.